# Calling different callbacks for stub on firstcall and second call

Tags: sinon

I'm looking for a way in sinon to call different functions in first and second call to the stub method.

Here is an example:

```js
var func1 = function(connectionPolicy, requestOptions, callback) {
  callback({code: 403});
}

var func2 = function(connectionPolicy, requestOptions, callback) {
  callback(undefined);
}

var stub = sinon.stub();

// Something of this form
stub.onCall(0) = func1;
stub.onCall(1) = func2;

request.createRequestObjectStub = stub;
```

So that when `request.createrequestObjectStub` gets called internally(when calling a public API), I see this behavior.

- Sinon version: 1.17.4
- Environment: Node JS

Answer (score 33):

The only way I found to do what you want (with `onCall(index)` and an anonymous stub) is with `bind` JS Function.

This would be:

```
stub.onCall(0).returns(func1.bind()());
stub.onCall(1).returns(func2.bind()());
```

If you use `stub.onCall(0).returns(func1());` the function `func1` is executed when defining that onCall, that is why you need the `.bind`.

Anyway, you have other options, like returning a value directly with `.onCall(index).returns(anObject);` or defining a counter that is incremented each time your stubbed method is called (this way you know in which n-call you are and you can return different values).

For these three approaches, you can see the following fiddle with examples: https://jsfiddle.net/elbecita/jhvvv1h1/

Answer (score 10):

onCall worked for me. 
my code looks like:

```
const stubFnc = sinon.stub(myObject, "myFunction");
stubFnc.onCall(0).returns(mockObject1);
stubFnc.onCall(1).returns(mockObject2);
```

Answer (score 5):

This is an old thread, but atleast as of Sinon 1.8, a more efficient way to solve this would be chaining `sinon.onCall(arg)` with `callsFake()`.

So, in your use-case, you could do the following:

```
var func1 = function(connectionPolicy, requestOptions, callback) {
    callback({code: 403});
}
var func2 = function(connectionPolicy, requestOptions, callback) {
    callback(undefined);
}

var stub = sinon.stub();

// Solution

stub.onCall(0).callsFake(func1);
stub.onCall(1).callsFake(func2);

request.createRequestObjectStub = stub;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `callsArg` and `callsArgWith` from sinon.stub() to make sinon call the callbacks

> Causes the stub to call the argument at the provided index as a callback function. stub.callsArg(0); causes the stub to call the first argument as a callback. [source](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v6.0.0/stubs/)

Then you can do something like:

```
  myStub.onCall(0).callsArgWith(0, first);
  myStub.onCall(1).callsArgWith(0, second);
```